# JWT Firebase PHP "kid" invalid, unable to lookup correct key

Tags: php, jwt

I generated a token using Firebase, when i try to fetch the data from database related to the token payload (email) i get the error "kid" invalid, unable to lookup correct key . the error is in the php file that must fetch data after verifying that a token exists

```
    $decoded = JWT::decode($token, base64_encode("100k@me@9t"), ['HS256']);
```

here is the code where i generate the token in login.php

```
<?php
//small exercise just to understand generating tokens and how to use it 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

include("connection.php");
include("vendor/autoload.php");
include_once("files/secretkey.php");


use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

$results = "";
$payloadData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


$email = $payloadData["logemail"];
$password = $payloadData["logpassword"];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?";
$select = $con->prepare($sql);
$select->execute([$email, $password]);
$user = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($user)) {
    
    // Generate the JWT token
    $payload = [
        "email" => $email,
        "name" => $user["firstname"]
    ];
    
    $token = JWT::encode($payload, base64_encode($secretKey) ,'HS256');


    $results = [
        "user" => $user,
        "token" => $token,
        "message" => "Success",
    ];
} else {
    $results = "Please Check your email and password.";
}

echo json_encode($results);


?>
```